# Motivo do uso de cursores em bancos de dados

Tags: sql, banco-de-dados

Entendo o que é um cursor, porém não entendo e não consegui ninguém que me mostre um motivo real para usá-los.

Por que devo usar cursores? Quero respostas com base no Oracle, SQL Server e MySQL e a diferença no uso de cursores entre eles.

Comment: Acho mais interessante foca-se apenas em cursores(sua teria de forma generica) sem citar SGDB's ou focar apenas em um. Pedir explicação de todos pode tornar a pergunta ampla.

Comment: Sua pergunta ficou ampla demais.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Você sabe que os cursores permitem acessar os dados selecionados de forma mais ou menos livre, ou seja você cria um conjunto de linhas de dados estáveis (mantém as mesmas linhas) que você pode circular por elas e fazer o que deseja.

Isso é interessante porque o volume de dados pode ser muito grande e carregar tudo pode ser um problema de memória e de carga, assim pode pegar as partes que interessam.

Também é útil porque pode precisar fazer análises e processamentos complexos que dependem de interações de código conforme vai "andando" pelos dados. De certa forma podemos dizer que pode fazer *streaming* dos dados. Se for algo simples é possível fazer sem cursores através das cláusulas `LIMIT` e `OFFSET` ou alternativas parecidas de cada banco de dados.

Algumas aplicações podem precisar receber os dados de uma forma específica. Embora possa trazer ineficiências.

Não que precise ser assim, mas ele costuma ser mais útil para DBAs ou programadores que agem como DBAs, em consultas de aplicações a utilidade é menor. Quase sempre as dificuldades de usá-lo corretamente faz você pensar em uma alternativa mais simples e confiável.

Cada banco de dados tem suas peculiaridades, a pergunta seria muito ampla falar do funcionamento de cada um.